# Open file with JFileChooser and display it in JFrame/JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

So Im trying to create swing gui in NetBeans IDE. Im new to java and building gui's so its been a little bit of a learning curve.

I created a JMenuItem called "Open" and used JFileChooser to open a file and display it. The file extension im limiting myself to is "*.map".

So i got my code working and it opens the chosen file in a new window on my desktop. But im trying to figure out how i can open the file inside of my JFrame and not a new window.
Its not a .txt file so i assume i cant use JTextArea or JTextField. Do i create a JPanel inside of my JFrame?

Here's a my ActionPerformed event code:

```
private void OpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try{
        JFileChooser chooser= new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("c:\\temp"));
        chooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("map","MAP"));
        int value = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if(value == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            String path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();

            File myFile = new File(path);
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
            messageLabel.setText("Map successfully Loaded!");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
```

Comment: What kind of file is a `.map` file ?

Comment: `Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);` will cause the OS to open the specified file with the app to which it is associated. To process it in the current application, you just need to call the logic instead of submitting it to the OS for processing.

Comment: So the .map file contains text with information about a place in the form " place placeName xpos ypos" so its a file describing a map with a series of records like  "place London 200 250"on each new line

Answer (score 0):

Ended up figuring out how to display the file in a JTextArea. Thanks for the responses guys. Here is my updated code and its working just as i wanted.

```html
    private void OpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                 
                JFileChooser chooser= new JFileChooser();
                chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("c:\\temp"));
                chooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("map","MAP"));
                int value = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                File f= chooser.getSelectedFile();
                String filename= f.getAbsolutePath();
                
                try{
                    FileReader reader = new FileReader(filename);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
                    jTextArea1.read(br,null);
                    br.close();
                    jTextArea1.requestFocus();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
                }
        
        
    }
```